# How to add the key and values in array?

Tags: php, arrays, addition

for example

```
$array1 = array(item1=>5,item2=>7);
$array2 = array(item1=>5,item3=>7);
```

Actually i want to first check the array, if same key exist means value should be (arithmetically) added otherwise 
if not exists then it directly pushed to the array.

my output will be like

```
$nov-2014 =array(item1=>10,item2=>7,item3=>7)
```

Comment: Just a note, every answer here assumes all the values will be numberical. Keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3):

You can just plainly use a simple for and a foreach for that purpose. Of course create the final container. Initialize values, then just continually add thru keys:

```
$array1 = array('item1'=>5,'item2'=>7);
$array2 = array('item1'=>5,'item3'=>7);

$result = array();
for($x = 1; $x <= 2; $x++) {
    foreach(${"array$x"} as $key => $values) {
        if(!isset($result[$key])) $result[$key] = 0; // initialize
        $result[$key] += $values; // add
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PgYOBM)

Comment: Please explain use of `${"array$x"}`

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com actually its a simple [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) concept, it basically iterates arrays `$array1` and `$array2`, oh i wish those arrays weren't separate, it could have been much easier, but anyway, i'l just have to work on what the OP got above there

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$array1 = array(
    'item1' => 5,
    'item2' => 7
);
$array2 = array(
    'item1' => 5,
    'item3' => 7
);
$array_new = $array2;
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    if (!in_array($key, $array2)) {
        $array_new[$key] = $value + $array2[$key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no built PHP function, use `foreach`.

```
$array1 = array('item1' => 5, 'item2' => 7);
$array2 = array('item1' => 5, 'item3' => 7);
$result = $array1;

foreach ($array2 as $key => $val) {
    if (isset($result[$key])) {
        $result[$key] += $val;
    } else {
        $result[$key] = $val;
    }
}

/*
    Output:
    Array
    (
        [item1] => 10
        [item2] => 7
        [item3] => 7
    )
*/
```

Answer (score -2):

Try [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). For associative arrays, this will keep same keys

Comment: It doesnt add the values when 5 exists 2 times.